# BMS for 2S Lipos

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, 12v, lipo

I have 2 [lipo batteries](https://www.gotronic.fr/art-accu-lipo-3-7-v-1000-mah-5813.htm#complte_desc) in series, each has a built in protection circuit and these specifications:

- Voltage: 3.7 Vcc
- Capacity: 1000 mAh
- Maximum discharge rate: 2100 mA

I need to charge them, but I already used them to power my raspberry, and now one battery has a voltage of 0.81 V and the other 3.7 V.

I tried to charge them with a [BMS](https://www.ebay.fr/itm/2S-5A-7-4v-8-4V-18650-BMS-PCM-protection-charge-batterie-li-ion-4112Z/183499949045?hash=item2ab97303f5:g:zlcAAOSwyPpc3JWT) but my stupidity struck back and I powered the BMS with a 12 V adapter and don't know if the BMS is working anymore.

I need help to know if I need to buy something else, and what is the best way to charge these batteries with my 12 V adapter.

N.B.
It is for a robot project, dimensions matter.

Comment: 0.81V is PROBABLY a dead cell. Try charging it with a 3 to 4V supply via a 1k resistor. It MAY "trickle up" in time but quite probably not. || If the BMS on that page is the one you have then it claims to stop discharge at 2.5-3V / cell. AND you cannot "POWER" a BMS. It connects to the 2 cells.  | To discharge a 2S pack to 3.7 + 0.81V = 4.5V you MUST be doing something very wrong. The lowest that it is sensible to 2S to is 6V (3+3). Your 4.5V looks like a very marginal 2.5 + 2.5 - a BMS should not go that low. And in cell protection SHOULD prevent the 0.81V.

Comment: I bought this BMS on ebay, I didn't find any datasheet except the description you can find here: https://www.ebay.fr/itm/2S-5A-7-4v-8-4V-18650-BMS-PCM-protection-charge-batterie-li-ion-4112Z/183499949045?hash=item2ab97303f5:g:zlcAAOSwyPpc3JWT

Comment: I could not identify the BMS control IC BUT similar ICs allow more than 20V input. IF you connected it to the 2 cells correctly it should not have had a battery fall to 0.8V.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that the lipo had a protection circuit, charging it completly with a correct voltage solved the problem.